# Python Requests - Download an SVG image along with referenced PNGs in <image> tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg, python-requests, imagemagick

There is a bunch of SVG files on the internet that I want to download using Python. Requests module seems fine for the job, but  tags exist within the code that reference images in the same domain.
E.g. `<image x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="img/1.png">`
 Downloading the SVG files and converting them to PNG using imagemagick would show errors like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGDYO.png).

Is there a way to easily download the referenced images too? Or even better, download the SVG as an errorless PNG all using Python?

Comment: i don't know module to do this - but `svg` is `xml` file so you could use `lxml` or `Beautifulsoup` to search `xlink:href` in `<image>` and download it with `requests`

Comment: The problem is that there is a referenced link to the image in the SVG file, rather than the file actually being imbedded.

Comment: as I said - use `lxml` or `Beautifulsoup` to search `xlink:href` in `<image>` to get `referenced link` and use `requests` to download `referenced link`

Comment: Please read the chapter `Adding SVG to your pages` in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web and explain which method is used on the page you are reading.

Comment: Is the `<image>` tag you mentioned above inside the SVG XML? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag ?

Comment: Can you manually download the PNG image if you put the full URL in the browser?

Comment: @Joe yes its inside the svg xml. yes i can manually download it. for example if the svg file was `https://examplefileserver.com/svgs/graphic.svg` then i can manually download `https://examplefileserver.com/svgs/img/1.png`. i know i can parse the svg xml but im asking about a better way to grab all of the referenced images.

Comment: Well, that's probably it. The only other thing I could think of is to just rely on the URL of the PNG being the same all the time and hardcode the URL + the image name of the SVG, remove the extension and replace with .png.